# Transforming elements of an array to fields in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

The data currently present in the MongoDB contains a bunch of attributes in an array of Strings, looking like that:

```
{ 
    ...,
    "person" : [
        ["John","Doe","22"],
        ["Jane","Doe","24"],
        ...
    ] 
}
```

the arrays are all structured similar so I would like to know if 
it is possible to transform the elements in the array to fields?
I am aiming to make a new collection with the data looking like this:

```
{ 
    ...,
    "person" : [
        {firstname:"John", lastname:"Doe", age:"22"},
        {firstname:"Jane", lastname:"Doe", age:"24"}
        ...
    ] 
}
```

I tried to aggregate it with $project, but to no success..
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your data to required format using aggregation and write that output to new collections.

```
//To convert data
{ 
    "person" : [
        ["John","Doe","22"],
        ["Jane","Doe","24"]
    ] 
}

//Aggregation to convert data to required format and write to new collection 'new_person'
db.persons.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind:"$person"
    },
    {
        $project: {
            firstName: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$person", 0 ] },
            lastName: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$person", 1 ] },
            age: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$person", 2 ] },
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            person : {$push: {firstName:"$firstName",lastName:"$lastName", age:"$age"}}
        }
    },
    {$out: "new_person"}
])

//Output:
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("594165e85bf0bf7801d042a7"),
    "person" : [
        {
            "firstName" : "John",
            "lastName" : "Doe",
            "age" : "22"
        },
        {
            "firstName" : "Jane",
            "lastName" : "Doe",
            "age" : "24"
        }
    ]
}
```